# Parse.com - Installation on update?

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I am using [parse.com](http://parse.com) for my backend database. My app is already published and I am adding a push notifications from parse. First I need to keep track of my [installations](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#installations/Android). But I have many users already that do not have an installation object saved for their device.

**My question is: when the user *updates* the app, will this count as an install?**

The reason I wonder, is cause I had an older version on my emulator, and updated it (with android studio) and it did not create an installation object for it.

This is how I save my installations:

> ```
>    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
> ```

On a fresh install, it will save the install object without a problem. Any suggestions? Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: google play dev console will give all installations right? or also you can use Google Analytics  right?

Comment: @LOG_TAG Yes.. I think so.. Why? I need to use parse install so I can use their push notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating my app on google play and my users that **updated** the app are being considered as a new install to parse. So there is no need to worry about specifically handling users with older versions. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Then what about the old installations? They are staying in the table as zombies.

Comment: @JDG Its been a while since I was doing this, so I may mislead you from here. But, what I mean as "considering it a new install", is it is saving a new `Installation` object to parse, and the device id will obviously be the same, so it should overwrite/update the previous one.

Comment: I found out that part, but what bothers me is those zombie installations when user uninstalled app. Even when user re-installed the app later (probably a newer version), those zombies still persist.

Comment: @JDG Yeah thats true. The only way I know to overcome that is if the users deletes their account. Otherwise AFAIK, we can't listen for uninstalls